# How to choose EC2 instance type for reverse proxy (4 million requests / month)

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

First time i have to create a reverse proxy on AWS, and i do not know with kind of instance to choose.

I plan to create an EC2 to load balance my traffic between a main website (/**) and a wordpress blog (/blog/**) with nginx.

I have to handle 1.000.000 requests a week (1000000/7/24/3600 ~= 2 requests seconds) and nothing else than nginx will run on this EC2.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any advice ?

**Don't guess it, benchmark it** and then adjust it. It's easy to switch between instance sizes in AWS so start with one that may be the right fit and observe how is it doing. Then increase or reduce the size to optimise your cost/performance.

By the way *2 requests per second* is not much, almost any instance should do. The problem is that it's probably not a uniform load, instead it will likely be going up and down and in peak times it could be a lot more. You may eventually want to have a look at *auto scaling*, but it may be an overkill.

Your usecase can also be handled by an **[Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html)** - you can create rules to direct the traffic to different backends based on the URL path. It can also handle SSL certificates for you, etc.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks you for your response @MLu. Friends are telling the same thing too, the ALB seems much more appropriate for this use case. Should i take care about something else if i use ALB ? Should i choose a size or it will automatically handle all the traffic ? How works the ALB pricing (a bill each month for all traffic handled for the month) ?

Comment: I found this tutorial, i'll really appreciate your input on it (that seems too easy for me, i'm afraid to have some issues if a point is not cover) https://medium.com/commutatus/how-to-configure-a-reverse-proxy-in-aws-b164de91176e#:~:text=Reverse%20proxy%20as%20the%20name,apps%20under%20the%20same%20hood.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @abenevaut Quickly scrolled through the tutorial and it seems spot-on. The GUI has changed a little but the concepts are correct: ALB, Listener, TargetGroups, etc. You can even configure it to handle HTTP to HTTPS redirection, and obtain a free certificate through ACM (Amazon Cert Manager). It scales with your traffic so no worries about the capacity. I’d personally do that rather than fiddling with nginx.

Comment: Thank you so much again for your time. I'll do this!

Comment: That's work well! Thanks again @MLu